# How to run a (linear) regression by group and add coefficients to the original data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, regression

I have a data.table where every row is an individual in different countries. How can I regress x on y separately for each country, and store the regression coefficient(s) for each country in the **original** data.table.

Lets say, the data.table Im speaking of is as follows to which I want to add two columns (intercept and slope of the regression I explained above)

```
set.seed(1)

dt = data.table(x=runif(40), y=runif(40), country=rep(1:2,20))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit

I didn't realize that you want to add to the original table. In this case, use `:=` in `j` as follows (the original answer, which returns only the summary, is kept at the end).

```
dt[, 
   c('slope', 'intercept') := { 
     fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = .SD)
     list(fit$coefficients[1], fit$coefficients[2])
   },
   by = country]
dt[]
##              x          y country     slope  intercept
##  1: 0.26550866 0.82094629       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
##  2: 0.37212390 0.64706019       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
##  3: 0.57285336 0.78293276       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
##  4: 0.90820779 0.55303631       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
##  5: 0.20168193 0.52971958       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
##  6: 0.89838968 0.78935623       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
##  7: 0.94467527 0.02333120       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
##  8: 0.66079779 0.47723007       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
##  9: 0.62911404 0.73231374       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 10: 0.06178627 0.69273156       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 11: 0.20597457 0.47761962       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 12: 0.17655675 0.86120948       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 13: 0.68702285 0.43809711       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 14: 0.38410372 0.24479728       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 15: 0.76984142 0.07067905       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 16: 0.49769924 0.09946616       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 17: 0.71761851 0.31627171       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 18: 0.99190609 0.51863426       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 19: 0.38003518 0.66200508       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 20: 0.77744522 0.40683019       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 21: 0.93470523 0.91287592       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 22: 0.21214252 0.29360337       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 23: 0.65167377 0.45906573       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 24: 0.12555510 0.33239467       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 25: 0.26722067 0.65087047       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 26: 0.38611409 0.25801678       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 27: 0.01339033 0.47854525       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 28: 0.38238796 0.76631067       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 29: 0.86969085 0.08424691       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 30: 0.34034900 0.87532133       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 31: 0.48208012 0.33907294       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 32: 0.59956583 0.83944035       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 33: 0.49354131 0.34668349       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 34: 0.18621760 0.33377493       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 35: 0.82737332 0.47635125       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 36: 0.66846674 0.89219834       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 37: 0.79423986 0.86433947       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 38: 0.10794363 0.38998954       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
## 39: 0.72371095 0.77732070       1 0.6275887 -0.2019328
## 40: 0.41127443 0.96061800       2 0.5042928  0.1252771
##              x          y country     slope  intercept
```

## Original answer

This is a perfect avenue for making use of the flexible `j` expression in `data.table`. You can put anything in `j` as long as it returns a list.

```
dt[, 
   { 
     fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = .SD)
     list(intercept = fit$coefficients[1], slope = fit$coefficients[2])
   },
   by = country]

#   country intercept   slope
#1:       1    0.6276 -0.2019
#2:       2    0.5043  0.1253
```

Comment: This is great and creates the stats I want. It only does not add the estimates (varying by country) to the original data.table. A combination of this with merge does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the whole thing can be done, extending Drumy's code:

```
set.seed(1)

dt = data.table(x=runif(40), y=runif(40), country=rep(1:2,20))

dt= merge(dt, dt[, 
   { 
     fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = .SD)
     list(intercept = fit$coefficients[1], slope = fit$coefficients[2])
   },
   by = country], by="country")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some core `tidyverse` packages along with `broom` this can be achieved like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

dt = data.table(x=runif(40), y=runif(40), country=rep(1:2,20))

dt %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(mod = map(data, ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .x)),
         mod_tidy = map(mod, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(mod_tidy) %>% 
  select(country, data, term, estimate) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "term", values_from = "estimate") %>% 
  rename(intercept = 3, slope = 4) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  as.data.table()
#>     country          x          y intercept      slope
#>  1:       1 0.26550866 0.82094629 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  2:       1 0.57285336 0.78293276 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  3:       1 0.20168193 0.52971958 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  4:       1 0.94467527 0.02333120 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  5:       1 0.62911404 0.73231374 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  6:       1 0.20597457 0.47761962 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  7:       1 0.68702285 0.43809711 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  8:       1 0.76984142 0.07067905 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#>  9:       1 0.71761851 0.31627171 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 10:       1 0.38003518 0.66200508 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 11:       1 0.93470523 0.91287592 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 12:       1 0.65167377 0.45906573 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 13:       1 0.26722067 0.65087047 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 14:       1 0.01339033 0.47854525 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 15:       1 0.86969085 0.08424691 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 16:       1 0.48208012 0.33907294 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 17:       1 0.49354131 0.34668349 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 18:       1 0.82737332 0.47635125 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 19:       1 0.79423986 0.86433947 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 20:       1 0.72371095 0.77732070 0.6275887 -0.2019328
#> 21:       2 0.37212390 0.64706019 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 22:       2 0.90820779 0.55303631 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 23:       2 0.89838968 0.78935623 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 24:       2 0.66079779 0.47723007 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 25:       2 0.06178627 0.69273156 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 26:       2 0.17655675 0.86120948 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 27:       2 0.38410372 0.24479728 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 28:       2 0.49769924 0.09946616 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 29:       2 0.99190609 0.51863426 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 30:       2 0.77744522 0.40683019 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 31:       2 0.21214252 0.29360337 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 32:       2 0.12555510 0.33239467 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 33:       2 0.38611409 0.25801678 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 34:       2 0.38238796 0.76631067 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 35:       2 0.34034900 0.87532133 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 36:       2 0.59956583 0.83944035 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 37:       2 0.18621760 0.33377493 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 38:       2 0.66846674 0.89219834 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 39:       2 0.10794363 0.38998954 0.5042928  0.1252771
#> 40:       2 0.41127443 0.96061800 0.5042928  0.1252771
#>     country          x          y intercept      slope
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>